# Negative offset a pattern in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Looking to use a grid image pattern that scales with the zoom. Once zoomed the grid re-aligns to the top left corner and misaligns the grid. To fix this I want to align the fabric image pattern to a **negative offset**. Currently negative offset doesn't change the offset of the pattern. Maybe there is another way to solve this issue that doesn't include a negative offset.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
  backgroundColor : "#FDF5E2"
})

canvas.setDimensions({
  width: window.innerWidth, 
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const zoom = 1.4

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/e2BzQYC.png', (img) => {
 img.scaleToWidth(25*zoom);

 let patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
 patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
 patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
 let pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
  source: () => {
   patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
    width: img.getScaledWidth(),
    height: img.getScaledHeight()
   });
   patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
   return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
  },
  repeat: 'repeat',
  offsetX: -12,
  offsetY: -12
 }); 

  canvas.setBackgroundColor(pattern, () => { canvas.renderAll(); })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-beta.7/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: that grid image starts from left/top = 0 right? What you want to acheive

Comment: I want it to start at left,top = -12 and each grid is 25 pixels. So it would be half way off.